# I want to know how to format the output for the print command in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have some python code that will extract names from a given link

```
from lxml import html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import sys
import os
import lxml.html
#url = sys.argv[1]
page = requests.get('https://streaming.ine.com/c/ine-comptia-a-plus-220-902')
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(page.content)
#name for each video
names = tree.xpath('//div[@class="cd-timeline-level"]/text()')
#sys.stdout = open("D:\\mytext.txt", "w")

print (*names)
```

The printed output is :

```
                                            Course Introduction



                                            Compare & Contrast Microsoft Operating Systems



                                            Installing Windows PC OS



                                            Applying Appropriate Microsoft Command Line Tools
```

But i want to be more like this :

01.Course Introduction

02.Compare & Contrast Microsoft Operating Systems

03.Installing Windows PC OS

04.Applying Appropriate Microsoft Command Line Tools

Whitout spaces between lines. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `strip` whitespaces and format text using code like this:

```
names = filter(lambda n: n.strip(), names)
for index, name in enumerate(names):
    print('{}. {}'.format(index, name.strip()))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's better now but still have some issues :  

0.

1. Course Introduction

2.

3.

4. Compare & Contrast Microsoft Operating Systems

5.

6.

7. Installing Windows PC OS

8.

9.

10. Applying Appropriate Microsoft Command Line Tools

11.

12.

13. Using Appropriate Microsoft Operating System Features & Tools

14.

15.

It show me each line for the beginning but with spaces between each line. And because of this, the lines are not numbered corectly.
Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much sir. It works like a charm!
Also if i need to put ".mp4" at each end of the line, how can be done ?
Thanks!

Comment: `print('{}. {}.mp4'.format(index, name.strip()))` will do it btw

Comment: Thanks again buddy. But i encoutered another problem : 

350. ACI FEX Configuration w/ Wizard :: Part 1
351. ACI FEX Configuration w/ Wizard :: Part 2
352. ACI FEX Manual Configuration
353. What is VMM Integration?

I want to remove special characters from the extracted names. You can see that in this output  there are "?", "::" and "/". 

Thanks!

Comment: Before loop do `table = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys('?:/'))` and in loop do `print('{}. {}.mp4'.format(index, name.strip().translate(table)))`